Is it possible to read properties defined in Unreal project's Target.cs in a module's Build.cs?
I have an Unreal module that is shared between several projects, and should be configured differently differently depending on the parent project. For example, the shared module needs to include something for one project, but ignore it in another.
I am trying to configure that using in UnrealBuildTool's .cs files for the project and module, like so:
// Project.target.cs
ProjectDefinitions.Add("USE_THIRD_PARTY_LIBRARY=true" /* or false, in another project's target.cs */);

// Module.build.cs
if (/* the USE_THIRD_PARTY_LIBRARY macro we defined in target.cs is true -- how to check this here? */) {
   PublicDependencyModuleNames.Add("SomeThirdPartyPlugin");
}

So, if the project defines a macro to be true, I'd like the module to be aware of that and configure itself differently. Is that possible, and if so, how?
